# Rijndael Encryption for different text generates same encrypted text?

Tags: security, encryption, rijndael

What are the chances that a Rijndael Encryption for two different texts could generate the same encrypted text.

Say I have a plain text

"abc" > encrypts to > "defdefdef"

Can this happen?

"hij"  > also encrypts to > "defdefdef"

Comment: Maybe a broken implementation or a null vector as a key?

Comment: @javex in that case "broken" would not even qualify it. It's more likely that the input would be skipped completely if this is to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same key, the chances are nil.  Different inputs map to different outputs with the same key.

For different keys, there is a minuscule probability that two different texts encrypted with two different keys happen to produce the same cipher text.  When I say minuscule, I mean negligible.  It is more likely that the Andromeda galaxy will park itself right next to the sun today.

Comment: Correct answer, except that the Andromeda galaxy is out next door neighbor, so relatively speaking, it's already next to the sun. For real: each plain text maps to exactly one ciphertext. As the function is two way over the same amount of bits, you cannot have the same ciphertext map back to the same plain text. It's precisely 1:1.